# Testing my iPad app on other device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I just tested my app out on my iPad and I want to show it to a friend. He sent me his UDID and but I don't know how I can send him the app. Please help me out , thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a adhoc build using his UUID. but first you have to create a adHoc provisioning profile from your developer portal. and then you can send the build and provisioning profile.

so first he has to drag and drop provisioning profile to his device then thru iTunes he can sync you app.

Answer (score 0):

Nnp described the process of how it usually is done.
If you'd like to do it easy way, and by easy I mean easy to you and your beta-testers (key features to me: over the air beta distribution, no more iTunes syncing, alert when new beta arrives, statistics), try [HockeyKit](http://hockeykit.net/) and optionally [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2011/5/25/hockeyapp-beyond-beta-distribution.html).